# Angular 6 RXJS HttpRequest Progress with multiple observables

Tags: rxjs, angular6, combinelatest

I have an array of observables each making an API request with different request Ids.

I'm currently using combineLatest to retrieve a HttpEvent object and attempting to calculate the progress downloaded within the callback.

However, combineLatest emits the entire response array for each observable, even if there isn't any progress attached to that HttpEvent.

I was wondering what the best rxjs/operator for combining multiple observables would be in this use-case?

Code:

```
    let featureDescriptionObsvs: Observable<any>[] = [];
    for (let key of Object.keys(res.breakdown)) {
    featureDescriptionObsvs.push(this.dataServ.getFeatureDescription(key));
    }
    combineLatest(...featureDescriptionObsvs).subscribe((events: any) => {

events.map((event: HttpEvent<any>): void => {
                    switch (event.type) {
                        case HttpEventType.Sent:
                            break;
                        case HttpEventType.ResponseHeader:
                            break;
                        case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
                            totalProgress += event.loaded / event.total;
                            break;
                        case HttpEventType.Response:
                            break;
                    }
                });
                let avgProgress = totalProgress / featureDescriptionObsvs.length;
                console.log(avgProgress * 100);
                console.log('\n');
            });
```